# Use android's camera

Tags: ros, camera, image, rosjava, video

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is there a way to get a video stream from an android phone's camera in the pc and publish it as a sensor_msgs/Image message?

Also, is there a package to convert a recorded video file into sensor_msgs/Image messages?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50173/use-android%27s-camera/) by [Pedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3142/pedro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/android_sensors_driver/)
doesn't say so, but the project site indicates that [android_sensors_driver](https://github.com/chadrockey/android_sensors_driver) does what you'd like.

As far as your video question, you could use [cv_bridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) or [ros2opencv](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ros2opencv?distro=fuerte).

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3142/pedro/) on 2012-12-12**:
Thanks! For now I'll just use a recorded video and cv_bridge worked fine.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-07-07**:
Now there is a separate app for streaming camera images, https://github.com/chadrockey/android_camera_driver